AWS Local build thinks something is too old but won't say what
I tried setting up AWS codebuild so I could do a local build on AWS. I followed the guidance on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-codebuild-agent.html
After doing the setup, I run
$ codebuild_build.sh -i my-builder -a /tmp/aws-codebuild 
Build Command:

docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "IMAGE_NAME=my-builder" -e "ARTIFACTS=/tmp/aws-codebuild" -e "SOURCE=/home/myuser/mystore-aws/mystore/build-environment" -e "INITIATOR=myuser" public.ecr.aws/codebuild/local-builds:latest

ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version
ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version

Where is it getting 1.22 or 1.24?
I'm running

Ubuntu 23.10
docker --version is 25.0.3
docker-compose --version is 1.29.2

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.What is too old and where do I upgrade it? If it's some Docker-compose file, please let me know where it's digging this up at.

I think those versions relate to the docker api version - anything below v1.24 is now deprecated. That probably means you need to tweak version 2 to 2.1 in a docker-compose file or similar. I would suggest checking the container logs with docker ps -a, then docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>? If nothing useful, you might need to run dockerd in debug mode. Theres not enough to give you an answer yet, edit your question with further detail

@MisterSmith I put the docker version I have in the text and it's substantially higher than 1.22. The docker build in the instructions were done with 25.0.3. Which image is it? Do I have to edit something from the AWS source?

docker version and docker api version are seperate things - tools like composer and docker itself use the api. Does seem that tuorial is out dated. Try using one of the newer images here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html that might fix your issue (or give you a different one :-)

Because the internal docker-compose version and docker-compose.yml version of the Docker Image (public.ecr.aws/codebuild/local-builds:latest) used for the build are out of date.
Starting with Docker Engine version 25.x.x, the supported API version has been increased to 1.24.
As a workaround, I would suggest downgrading the Docker Engine version to 24.
FYI:
codebuild_build.sh is using local Docker daemon in building process. (-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock)
So we need to match the version of the local Docker daemon and Docker Compose inside local-builds.
Update(2024/04/30):
I tried to create the modified docker image and it's well done.
command:
$ mkdir local-builds-v3 && cd local-builds-v3
$ docker build -t local-builds-v3:latest .
$ cd /path/to/your/projectroot
$ ./codebuild_build.sh -i my-builder -a /tmp/aws-codebuild -l local-builds-v3 # for specify builder-agent-image (-l)

Dockerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/codebuild/local-builds:latest

RUN <<EOT
  for file in '/LocalBuild/agent-resources/docker-compose.yml' '/LocalBuild/agent-resources/docker-compose-mount-src-dir.yml'
  do
    sed -i -e "s/^version: '2'/version: '3'/" ${file}
    sed -i -e "s/BMR:3000/agent:3000/g" ${file}
    sed -i -e "/links:/d" ${file}
    sed -i -e "/agent:BMR/d" ${file}
  done
EOT


Verified. Did someone tell AWS ?
